# Flux/Alt Basic async example throws "Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch"

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm struggling to get around the `Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch` error Flux is throwing at me, with a basic example.

On my view, I've got a button which triggers a `socialLogin(token)` action, on my `AuthActions`. With Alt on my Action, I `generateActions('login');`

My `socialLogin` method performs an Async API request which returns a promise (`Api` is a simple class using a request lib):

```
// AuthActions
socialLogin(type, access_token) {
    Api.request('get', 'auth/social', { type, access_token })
       .then((payload) => {
           if (payload.code !== 'OK') {
               // Do something...
           } else {
               this.actions.login(payload.data.token);
           }
       })
       .catch((response) => {
           console.log('ERROR', response);
           // Do something....
       });
    this.dispatch();
}
```

The Store `onLogin` method currently does nothing.

However running this throws/catches the error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.(…)`.

I cannot understand why, after reading many issues/articles - shouldn't the `this.dispatch()` "resolve" the current action being dispatched?

How would I go about triggering some other action here, or even trigger multiple actions (login, use another external action etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think in your example you can just omit the `this.dispatch();` line entirely, and it should. The action creator function `socialLogin` is called as part of a dispatch itself, so it is not allowed to call dispatch. If you do want to dispatch a socialLogin action at the start of the login process (e.g. to allow putting up a spinner or something), you could return the payload you want to dispatch. e.g. replace `this.dispatch();` with

```
return { type, access_token };
```

That way stores can listen to socialLogin if they want to catch the start of the process.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is `this.actions.myAnotherAction()`, where `myAnotherAction` is another action within the `AuthActions` in your case. Look

Answer (score 0):

inside the action, just return a promise like:

```
 socialLogin(type, access_token) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type:type, accessToken:access_token});
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      Api.request('get', 'auth/social', { type, access_token })
      .then((payload) => {
       if (payload.code !== 'OK') {
           // Do something...
       } else {
           this.actions.login(payload.data.token);
       }
       resolve(payload);
       })
       .catch((response) => {
       console.log('ERROR', response);
       // Do something....
       reject(response);
       });
    }
  }

}
```

Also sometimes in the container/controller views, you might be calling actions as a result of this action which will lead to the same error. In that just call any subsequent acction with defer option in dispatch like:

```
  myaction.actionname.defer(options);
```